# I want to fetch all table level user role and permission in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, user-permissions

I have a database in sql-server. I want to fetch all user and their permission on table level.

```
select 
    permission_name, state_desc, type_desc, U.name, OBJECT_NAME(major_id) 
from 
    sys.database_permissions P 
    JOIN sys.tables T ON P.major_id = T.object_id 
    JOIN sysusers U ON U.uid = P.grantee_principal_id;
```

I used this query also but it's giving empty result list

Comment: i want a query to fetch all table level roles and permission

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: select permission_name, state_desc, type_desc, U.name, OBJECT_NAME(major_id) 
from sys.database_permissions P 
JOIN sys.tables T ON P.major_id = T.object_id 
JOIN sysusers U ON U.uid = P.grantee_principal_id;   I used this query also but it's giving empty result list.

Answer (score 0):

```
select permission_name, state_desc, type_desc, U.name, OBJECT_NAME(major_id) 
from sys.database_permissions P 
JOIN sys.tables T ON P.major_id = T.object_id 
JOIN sysusers U ON U.uid = P.grantee_principal_id
```

Try this.

This will only show custom users made on that specific table. As for system users etc. I'm not too sure.

**EDIT**

To retrieve the system users it can be quiet hard. Here's 2 to aid you.

```
USE master
GO

SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.name AS [loginname] ,
        --p.type,
        p.type_desc ,
        p.is_disabled,
        s.sysadmin,
        sp.permission_name
FROM sys.server_principals p
INNER JOIN sys.syslogins s ON p.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN sys.server_permissions sp ON p.principal_id = sp.grantee_principal_id
WHERE p.type_desc IN ('SQL_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP')
    -- Logins that are not process logins
    AND p.name NOT LIKE '##%'
ORDER BY p.name
GO
```

and

```
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END,  
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
    [Role] = null,      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
    princ.[type] in ('S','U')
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END, 
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT  
    [UserName] = '{All Users}',
    [UserType] = '{All Users}', 
    [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',       
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],  
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]                   
JOIN 
    --All objects   
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
    princ.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```

Comment: Thanks. But its giving me empty result list. As I want custom user as well system user list